# How to inflate Views like in Activity, so that TextView will become MaterialTextView, for example?

Tags: android, layout-inflater

### Background

I work on an app that doesn't always have an `Activity` (or `AppCompatActivity` to be precise). Sometimes it has a floating UI instead (using SAW permission), so it has only `ApplicationContext`.

### The problem

Some of the UI is inflated there, and it could be nice to use the latest material libraries.

One example is `MaterialTextView`, which on normal situations it's inflated to replace `TextView` in the layout file:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello World!" app:drawableStartCompat="@drawable/customringtone" />

</FrameLayout>
```

For this example alone, I will demonstrate it in an `Activity`. This would let the `TextView` to show its drawable:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this)
        val binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(inflater, null, false)
        setContentView(binding.root)
    }
}
```

But, to show you how it works outside, use it a different inflater, which doesn't use the `Activity`:

```
val inflater =
    LayoutInflater.from(android.view.ContextThemeWrapper(applicationContext, R.style.AppTheme))
```

And the theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Material3.Light.NoActionBar">
</style>
```

In this case, the drawable of the `TextView` doesn't show up, and indeed if I check it in code (using `compoundDrawablesRelative` and `compoundDrawables` on it), I can see it has no drawables.

So, currently the workaround I have is to use `MaterialTextView` on my own, or use the older attributes and let the IDE ignore the suggestion to use `app:drawableStartCompat`.

EDIT: later when talking with Google, they [**wrote me**](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/283715194#comment6):

> This is already available via the AppCompatViewInflater API.
>
> You install the [**AppCompatViewInflater**](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatViewInflater) API by creating an
> implementation of the LayoutInflater.Factory2 interface, overriding
> its onCreateView APIs to call AppCompatViewInflater's createView API.
> You can then install the factory onto your LayoutInflater via
> LayoutInflaterCompat.setFactory2(layoutInflater, yourFactory). See the
> source code for [**AppCompatDelegateImpl**](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:appcompat/appcompat/src/main/java/androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatDelegateImpl.java;l=1710) for an example.

Thing is, this solution has multiple issues:

1. A lot of private functions
2. A lot of code to copy
3. very fragile as it depends on a library's implementation and relation between quite inner classes, but it won't work because it fails to be built.

Still, wanted to try (wrote about it [**here**](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/284737593)):

```
import android.content.Context
import android.content.res.TypedArray
import android.os.Build
import android.util.*
import android.view.*
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater
import androidx.appcompat.widget.VectorEnabledTintResources
import androidx.core.view.LayoutInflaterCompat
object MaterialInflater {

    fun getMaterialInflater(context: Context): LayoutInflater {
        val factory = object : LayoutInflater.Factory2 {
            private var mAppCompatViewInflater: AppCompatViewInflater? = null

            override fun onCreateView(parent: View?, name: String, context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet): View? {
                return createView(parent, name, context, attrs);
            }

            override fun onCreateView(name: String, context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet): View? {
                return onCreateView(null, name, context, attrs);
            }

            fun createView(parent: View?, name: String?, context: Context,
                attrs: AttributeSet): View? {
                var appCompatViewInflater = mAppCompatViewInflater
                if (appCompatViewInflater == null) {
                    val a: TypedArray =
                        context.obtainStyledAttributes(androidx.appcompat.R.styleable.AppCompatTheme)
                    val viewInflaterClassName =
                        a.getString(androidx.appcompat.R.styleable.AppCompatTheme_viewInflaterClass)
                    a.recycle()
                    appCompatViewInflater = if (viewInflaterClassName == null) {
                        // Set to null (the default in all AppCompat themes). Create the base inflater
                        // (no reflection)
                        AppCompatViewInflater()
                    } else {
                        try {
                            val viewInflaterClass: Class<*> =
                                context.classLoader.loadClass(viewInflaterClassName)
                            viewInflaterClass.getDeclaredConstructor()
                                .newInstance() as AppCompatViewInflater
                        } catch (t: Throwable) {
                            //                            Log.i(TAG, "Failed to instantiate custom view inflater "
                            //                                    + viewInflaterClassName + ". Falling back to default.", t)
                            AppCompatViewInflater()
                        }
                    }
                    mAppCompatViewInflater = appCompatViewInflater
                }

                return appCompatViewInflater.createView(parent, name!!, context, attrs, false,
                    false,  /* Only read android:theme pre-L (L+ handles this anyway) */
                    true,  /* Read read app:theme as a fallback at all times for legacy reasons */
                    VectorEnabledTintResources.shouldBeUsed() /* Only tint wrap the context if enabled */
                )
            }
        }
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)!!
        LayoutInflaterCompat.setFactory2(layoutInflater, factory)
        return layoutInflater
    }
}
```

It shows an error due to using 2 private functions:

- appCompatViewInflater.createView
- VectorEnabledTintResources.shouldBeUsed()

The error is:

```
e: file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/MyApplication/app/src/main/java/com/lb/myapplication/Foo.kt:64:46 Cannot access 'createView': it is package-private in 'AppCompatViewInflater'
```

And that's before I even try to use this new code...

### The questions

How can I make it work like on `Activity`, so that the inflater will replace all Views to the material version of them?

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer to this question? If so, it looks to me like you have two issues: Replacing framework views with Material views, and, getting attribute values from your theme instead of the default system theme. Can I assume that you are using a Service?

Comment: @Cheticamp Why does it matter that it's a Service?

Comment: Just want to identify the precise environment. It may or may not matter.

Comment: @Cheticamp Please assume that I provide Application.

Comment: Do you agree regarding the two issues in my comment?

Comment: @Cheticamp I think it's both done anyway together in the same class/es that inflates everything. I've read that AppCompatViewInflater . I've updated my question now with my findings, as I forgot that I should have written them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modifiers for *AppcompatViewInflator#createView* changed from `final View createView` to `public final View createView` between AppCompat versions 1.5.1 and 1.6.0. Although Android Studio complains about `VectorEnabledTintResources.shouldBeUsed()`, it can still be successfully called.

A Material LayoutInflater can be built as follows for AppCompat versions 1.6.0 and later.

```
private fun getMaterialInflater(context: Context, @StyleRes theme: Int): LayoutInflater {
    val inflater = ContextThemeWrapper(context, theme).run {
        getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
    }

    val factory = object : LayoutInflater.Factory2 {
        val myInflater = MaterialComponentsViewInflater()

        override fun onCreateView(
            parent: View?,
            name: String,
            context: Context,
            attrs: AttributeSet
        ): View? {

            return myInflater.createView(
                parent,
                name,
                context,
                attrs,
                false, // "true" to use the parent's context
                false, // androidTheme: Emulate the android:theme attribute for devices before L.
                true, // appTheme: Emulate the android:theme attribute for devices before L.
                VectorEnabledTintResources.shouldBeUsed() /* Only tint wrap the context if enabled */
            )
        }

        override fun onCreateView(name: String, context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet): View? {
            return onCreateView(null, name, context, attrs)
        }

    }
    LayoutInflaterCompat.setFactory2(inflater, factory)
    return inflater
}
```

Here is how we can inflate a layout using our *MaterialInflater*.

```
getMaterialInflater().inflate(R.layout.overlay_view, null)
```

I have placed the above code into a Service and inflated the following layout as a screen overlay:

```
<FrameLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:drawableTint="?colorAccent"
        android:text="I'm a Material witness."
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:drawableStartCompat="@drawable/baseline_wifi_24" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Here is the service code I used for the demo:

```
class OverlayService : Service() {
    private val mWindowManager by lazy {
        getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
    }
    private lateinit var mOverlayView: View

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        startForeground(1, getNotification())
        mOverlayView = createOverlayView()

        // Click for graceless exit.
        mOverlayView.setOnClickListener {
            stopSelf()
        }
        addOverlayViewToWindow(mOverlayView)
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int) = START_NOT_STICKY

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        mWindowManager.removeView(mOverlayView)
    }

    private fun getMaterialInflater(context: Context, @StyleRes theme: Int): LayoutInflater {
        val inflater = ContextThemeWrapper(context, theme).run {
            getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        }

        val factory = object : LayoutInflater.Factory2 {
            val myInflater = MaterialComponentsViewInflater()

            override fun onCreateView(
                parent: View?,
                name: String,
                context: Context,
                attrs: AttributeSet
            ): View? {

                return myInflater.createView(
                    parent,
                    name,
                    context,
                    attrs,
                    false, // "true" to use the parent's context
                    false, // androidTheme: Emulate the android:theme attribute for devices before L.
                    true, // appTheme: Emulate the android:theme attribute for devices before L.
                    VectorEnabledTintResources.shouldBeUsed() /* Only tint wrap the context if enabled */
                )
            }

            override fun onCreateView(name: String, context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet): View? {
                return onCreateView(null, name, context, attrs)
            }

        }
        LayoutInflaterCompat.setFactory2(inflater, factory)
        return inflater
    }

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    private fun createOverlayView(): View {
        return getMaterialInflater(
            this, // The service's context
            R.style.Theme_MyMaterialTheme_Service // Theme to use for inflation
        ).inflate(R.layout.overlay_view, null)
    }

    private fun addOverlayViewToWindow(overlayView: View) {
        val params = LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
            LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE or
                    LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL or
                    LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
        )

        mWindowManager.addView(overlayView, params)
    }

    private fun getNotification(): Notification {
        val channel = NotificationChannel(
            NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID,
            CHANNEL_NAME,
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN
        )
        val manager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        manager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        val notificationBuilder =
            NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setForegroundServiceBehavior(FOREGROUND_SERVICE_IMMEDIATE)
        return notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
            .setContentTitle("Demo overlay app is running")
            .setContentText("Displaying over other apps")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.baseline_wifi_24)
            .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN)
            .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
            .build()
    }

    private companion object {
        const val NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "demoapp.notouch"
        const val CHANNEL_NAME = "Foreground Service"
    }
}
```

Comment: Wait, are you sure you've tested it with Application as Context ? It shows "this". My function gets "Context" as a parameter, so that you could use any that you wish.

Comment: @androiddeveloper OK. See updated code using the application's context. There is no change to the output.

Comment: This should work exactly like when inside Activity?

Comment: @androiddeveloper It should although I have not extensively tested it. The various hard-coded parameters to createView() would have to be researched to determine how they should be set under varying conditions. I just coded what I thought was reasonable. –

Comment: @androiddevelop Updated with  solution using Reflection.

Comment: Why the need for the reflection? Because of access to private stuff of the library?

Comment: @androiddeveloper Yes, to access the private stuff. It's just a second way that has the benefit of being just a few lines of code. These are two ways of accomplishing what you asked with what is available.

Comment: I don't understand how to use what you've made. Where is "MyMaterialComponentsViewInflater" ? I have just one class, and one function inside. It gets Context as a parameter. Doesn't matter which. 
Even when using `MaterialInflaterDelegate`, the `LayoutInflater.Factory2` requires a call to `onCreateView(name: String, context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet)` . Please show full code of both ways.

Comment: For MyMaterialComponentsViewInflater just copy [MaterialComponentsViewInflater](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/theme/MaterialComponentsViewInflater.java), change the package and change "extends AppCompatViewInflater" to "extends MyAppCompatViewInflater". MyAppCompatViewInflater is a copy of AppCompatViewInflater.java with the new package. @androiddeveloper

Comment: AppCompatViewInflater.java is [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/f2e05c341382db64d127118a13451dcaa554b702/appcompat/appcompat/src/main/java/androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatViewInflater.java). You can get both classes from the SDK.

Comment: With the Reflection solution, you won't have to copy any code from the SDK.  Simpler, but involves Reflection.  @androiddeveloper

Comment: About the first solution, so you say I should copy classes of the Material library, but I wanted to use the library so that it will do the exact same as the library, even if I update the dependency . I don't understand how the MaterialInflaterDelegate should be used. Will it remove the need to copy the library classes? How would this new class be used in the getMaterialInflater function? The callCreateView doesn't fit the parameters needed for the createView parameters (8 parameters vs 3)

Comment: BTW, the AppCompatViewInflater just returns null for the `createView(Context context, String name, AttributeSet attrs)` ... And, whether I use the copied classses or not, I get `IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).` , even though the theme I've provided already has this as parent. Here, a sample of it (would be in Github once it's working) : https://easyupload.io/q3264f

Comment: @androiddeveloper I did notice that null was returned. To get that method working, you would need to make some assumptions to call the `createView()` with the longer argument list. As for the _IllegalArgumentException_, you might want to check that the context you are using is wrapped with the context with a Material style.

Comment: @androiddeveloper I added the service code I used for the demo to the answer. I also made some slight modifications to `getMaterialInflater()`.

Comment: Now it works, but you don't need any class to be copied from the material library. You can work with it directly. I don't understand in which line of what I got was the cause to the exception.  BTW, you used something you shouldn't : lockscreenVisibility

Comment: @androiddeveloper You're right. I don't know why I thought the method was private and needed a copy to work. I will change the answer to reflect this.

Comment: @androiddeveloper I found the source of confusion. The modifiers for _AppcompatViewInflator@createView_ changed from `final View createView` to `public final View createView` between AppCompat versions 1.5.1 and 1.6.0.

Comment: Confusion of what? Also, I suggest to use the material dependency instead of appcompat

Comment: You said _" I don't understand in which line of what I got was the cause to the exception. "_. The error was that `createView()` was private. The access to `createView()` was change to `public` after version 1.5.1 of AppCompat.

Comment: I don't know. I use material dependency instead of appCompat. Otherwise weird things can happen

Comment: I think I can see the issue of the access to `createView` on another app. How did you fix it? I can't find what's wrong...

Comment: @androiddeveloper Update to at least version 1.6.0 of AppCompat in your gradle file. You may also need to update the Material library to a later verion. I use 1.9.0.

Comment: I think you are right. The issue can also be solved when using a newer version of material (example: 1.11.0-alpha01) , alone. Weird thing is that on the problematic app, if I add this code into the main module which doesn't have appcompat, it's fine, and in another module it's not. There is probably yet another dependency that makes it more updated, and then the function `createView` is public.

Comment: BTW, you should use `StyleRes` annotation. not `Identifier` . It's a style/theme. Not a View ID .